# Null Pointer Exception when contacts saving into mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, android-fragments, android-contacts

I want to save all the contacts into my MySql database,that I retrieved  from Contactcontract table,when I intend to save the contact into database it gives me a error of null pointer exception,I am calling this in oncreate function, and pass the contacts attribute to other class for further process.

Given below is some part of my source code:

```
public class ContactsListFragment extends ListFragment implements
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

        // Defines a tag for identifying log entries
        private static final String TAG = "ContactsListFragment";

        // Bundle key for saving previously selected search result item
        private static final String STATE_PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_KEY =
                "com.example.android.contactslist.ui.SELECTED_ITEM";

        private static final Cursor Cursor = null;
         public    DBHandler db;

        private ContactsAdapter mAdapter; // The main query adapter
        private ImageLoader mImageLoader; // Handles loading the contact image in a background thread
        private String mSearchTerm; // Stores the current search query term

        // Contact selected listener that allows the activity holding this fragment to be notified of
        // a contact being selected
        private OnContactsInteractionListener mOnContactSelectedListener;

        // Stores the previously selected search item so that on a configuration change the same item
        // can be reselected again
        private int mPreviouslySelectedSearchItem = 0;

        // Whether or not the search query has changed since the last time the loader was refreshed
        private boolean mSearchQueryChanged;

        // Whether or not this fragment is showing in a two-pane layout
        private boolean mIsTwoPaneLayout;

        // Whether or not this is a search result view of this fragment, only used on pre-honeycomb
        // OS versions as search results are shown in-line via Action Bar search from honeycomb onward
        private boolean mIsSearchResultView = false;

        /**
         * Fragments require an empty constructor.
         */
        public ContactsListFragment() {}


         *
         * @param query The contacts search query.
         */
        public void setSearchQuery(String query) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                mIsSearchResultView = false;
            } else {
                mSearchTerm = query;
                mIsSearchResultView = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            // corresponding resource size-qualified directory.
            mIsTwoPaneLayout = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.has_two_panes);

            // Let this fragment contribute menu items
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            Log.d("Hope","Hope 3");

            // Create the main contacts adapter
            mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity());

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // If we're restoring state after this fragment was recreated then
                // retrieve previous search term and previously selected search
                // result.
                mSearchTerm = savedInstanceState.getString(SearchManager.QUERY);
                mPreviouslySelectedSearchItem =
                        savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_PREVIOUSLY_SELECTED_KEY, 0);
            }



            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity(), getListPreferredItemHeight()) {
                @Override
                protected Bitmap processBitmap(Object data) {
                    // This gets called in a background thread and passed the data from
                    // ImageLoader.loadImage().
                    return loadContactPhotoThumbnail((String) data, getImageSize());
                }
            };
```

**HERE I am trying to save all the contact to mysqldatabase**

```
           **SavingContacts savingcontacts=new SavingContacts();

            final String ContactID = Cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.ID);
             final String Lookup = Cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.LOOKUP_KEY);
             final String displayName = Cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.DISPLAY_NAME);
            final String photoUri = Cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_DATA);
             savingcontacts.savingcontact(ContactID, displayName, photoUri, Lookup);**
            // Set a placeholder loading image for the image loader
            mImageLoader.setLoadingImage(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture_holo_light);

            // Add a cache to the image loader
            mImageLoader.addImageCache(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), 0.1f);
        }
```

This is my logcat:

```
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.contactslist/com.example.android.contactslist.ui.ContactsListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at com.example.android.contactslist.ui.ContactsListActivity.onCreate(ContactsListActivity.java:65)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    ... 11 more
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at com.example.android.contactslist.ui.ContactsListFragment.onCreate(ContactsListFragment.java:198)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
02-18 23:35:11.212: E/AndroidRuntime(21479):    ... 19 more
```

Comment: which is line number `198` in ContactsListFragment ?

Comment: final String ContactID = Cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.ID); that one,

Comment: where you are initializing `Cursor` ?

Comment: I already mentioned this line inthe above code,

Comment: private static final Cursor Cursor = null;

Comment: I initialize the cursor at start of the class i didnot paste the whole code but just small part of this